# Find right URLs using Python and regex

Tags: python, regex, url

I have a table with urls like

```
vk.com/albums54751623?z=photo54751623_341094858%2Fphotos54751623
vk.com/albums54751623
vk.com/id36375649
vk.com/id36375649
```

I need to find all `urls` like `vk.com/id36375649` (only `id`)
I try

```
for url in urls:
    if url == re.compile('vk.com/^[a-z0-9]'):
        print url
    else:
        continue
```

but this is uncorrectly, because it didn't return anything

Comment: try 'vk\.com\/id\d+'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startswith`:

```
strs = ['vk.com/albums54751623?z=photo54751623_341094858%2Fphotos54751623',
'vk.com/albums54751623',
'vk.com/id36375649',
'vk.com/id36375649']
print([x for x in strs if x.startswith(r'vk.com/id')])
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/A6hg8r)

*UPDATE*

To address the issues stated in comments below this answer, you will have to use a regex with some checks:

```
^vk\.com/(?!album)\w+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB7mD7/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4iCxnX):

```
import re
strs = ['vk.com/albums54751623?z=photo54751623_341094858%2Fphotos54751623',
'vk.com/albums54751623',
'vk.com/id36375649',
'vk.com/id36375649',
'vk.com/id36375649?z=album-28413960_228518010',
'vk.com/tania_sevostianova'
]
print([x for x in strs if re.search(r'^vk\.com/(?!album)\w+$', x)])
# => ['vk.com/id36375649', 'vk.com/id36375649', 'vk.com/tania_sevostianova']
```

Comment: Nice! You don't always need regex :)

Comment: I think a regex is not necessary in case there is a good language method for that, and when the data is clean and structured. If that is not the case, sure, a regex like [`r'vk\.com/id\d+'`](https://ideone.com/0Yx1Nh) can be very handy

Comment: Some urls like `vk.com/id36375649?z=album-28413960_228518010`. I don't need that

Comment: Do you mean you do not want a vk.com ID link with a query string?

Comment: And some `urls instead number of `id` contains `nickname` like `vk.com/tania_sevostianova`. I need to get that too

Comment: I need only `ID`. but if after the number there is something else I do not need this `urls`

Comment: You are changing the question on the fly. You may try a regex then. Try [`r'^vk\.com/(?!album)\w+$'`](https://regex101.com/r/rB7mD7/1). See the update.

Comment: I do not know how to form my question. Some `url` can relate to the person or to the community. For example `vk.com/tania_sevostianova` it is person, but `vk.com/mvgtaobao` is the community. I need only person. Is there a way to define it?

Comment: No, there is no way without a kind of a dictionary to check against. A name of the community can be equal to a name *unless* there is some *pattern* that helps differentiate them (say, the person ID should contain `_`, but I doubt it can be used as a differentiator). Perhaps, the best way is to go to that page and check what it is (use some Web scraping tools/code).

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression like the following might work

```
vk.com\/id\d+
```

Remember that in regex you need to escape certain characters like slashes.